# Messed up a USDT transfer, sent from Sol network to Ethereum network

Tags: transactions, wallet, transfer

Sent some USDT from my Phantom wallet to my Coinbase and accidentally sent from Sol to Ethereum networks. The transfer was successful and went through but funds never showed up. I called Coinbase who was able to locate it but couldn't do anything because it wasn't on Ethereum network. Hoping someone might have some advise on what to do from here? Thanks.